# odd behavior while looping through an unicode string

Tags: python, unicode

When I do:

```
text = u"奥巴马讲话"
for c in text:
    print c
```

I got the expected result:

```
奥
巴
马
讲
话
```

But if I do:

```
text = u"€"
for c in text:
    print c
```

I got:

```
�
�
€
```

I'm expecting to get:

```
€
```

Why is this?  I think it has something to do with the following fact:

```
In [1]: u"".encode("utf8")
Out[1]: '\xf0\xa4\xad\xa2'
```

"" is encoded using 4 bytes.

How can I loop through an unicode string that has this kind of encoding?

Something like u"".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is outside the Basic Multilingual Plane; it has codepoint U+24B62. This means that to process it correctly you need a Python build that has `sys.maxunicode == 1114111`.  See [Unicode in Python - just UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095499/unicode-in-python-just-utf-16) for more details.

If you can, upgrade to Python 3.3 where this is all handled correctly.  Otherwise you will need to implement UTF-16 handling yourself by pairing up low and high surrogate codepoints: [How to iterate over Unicode characters in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494064/how-to-iterate-over-unicode-characters-in-python-3?lq=1)