# Counting nuumber of emoticons in tweets extracted in a file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, unicode, emoticons

i have extraxted a number of tweets ( utf-8) in a csv file. I am trying to run a python code to count number of emoticons in each tweet.The emoticons appear in the file as follows:-
 ðŸ’©ðŸ’©ðŸ’©ðŸ’©ðŸ’©

---

Now i dont know how to identify these.
I tried to covert the whole tring to unicode and then counting them by following code:
  `s=str(strs, "unicode")
    print(s)
    print(strs)
    emoti = re.finditer(r'[\U0001f600-\U0001f650]', s)
    count = sum(1 for _ in emoti)`

---

but it gives an error as-decoding str is not supported
I cant collect all the tweets again, i need to count no. of emoticons on the same set of tweets. can any body tell how to go about it?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: There is no unicode in python3.

Comment: then how should i count emoticons?

Comment: Read the answers here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146528/how-to-extract-all-the-emojis-from-text/43147265#43147265

Answer (score 0):

If this string is what you have:

```
'ðŸ’©ðŸ’©ðŸ’©ðŸ’©ðŸ’©'
```

It has been decoded with the wrong codec.  It looks like `cp1252` (the Windows ANSI default).  Re-encode it with the incorrect coded used, then decode it with `utf8`.  Better yet, fix the source of the incorrect decoding.

```
>>> 'ðŸ’©ðŸ’©ðŸ’©ðŸ’©ðŸ’©'.encode('cp1252')
b'\xf0\x9f\x92\xa9\xf0\x9f\x92\xa9\xf0\x9f\x92\xa9\xf0\x9f\x92\xa9\xf0\x9f\x92\xa9'
>>> 'ðŸ’©ðŸ’©ðŸ’©ðŸ’©ðŸ’©'.encode('cp1252').decode('utf8')
''
```

Unfortunately there is not a single range of Unicode characters for emoji.  See [emoji-test.txt](http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/4.0/emoji-test.txt) from the unicode.org website.  That particular character is U+1F4A9, and is outside the Unicode range you have specified in your sample code.