# how to extarct emoji from a given sentance using python

Tags: python-3.x, emoji, sentiment-analysis, emoticons

I want to extract all the emoji from a given sentence and want to change the emoji to their respective unicode. How would it be possible in python?

For example, a given sentence might be: `sentence = "happy  .well done "`

Comment: What do you mean by "change the emoji to their respective unicode"? Unicode is just a standard assigning each character from a finite but periodically expanding set of characters a unique non-negative integer number. It's not even an encoding (utf-8, utf-16 and utf-32 are). Do you mean you need to represent the emoji as python escape sequences? Like this `''` -> `'\U0001f60a'`?

Comment: yes i like this '' -> '\U0001f60a'?

Comment: Sorry. I was in a hurry. The correct literal for the string would be '\\U0001f60a'.

Comment: Will code that turns all non-ascii characters into escape sequences suffice or do you need something that only escapes emoji?

Comment: i need to extract emoji from sentence and change the emoji like this '' -> '\U0001f60a'...this will be matched with database we have created

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract all the emojis from text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146528/how-to-extract-all-the-emojis-from-text)

Comment: @JoshLee So there *is* an emoji python library. I should have searched harder. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it might be late but this answer might be useful for you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43146653