# Extract Unicode-Emoticons in list, Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, emoticons

I work on some twitter-data and I want to filter the emoticons in a list. The data itself is encoded in utf8. 
I read the file in line by line like these three example lines:

```
['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'tweet', 'with', 'two', 'emoticons', '', '⚓️']
['This', 'is', 'another', 'tweet', 'with', 'a', 'emoticon', '']
['This', 'tweet', 'contains', 'no', 'emoticon']
```

I'd like to collect the emoticons for each line like that:

```
['', '⚓️']
```

and so on.

I already researched and found that there's an 'emoji' package in python. I tried to use it in my code like that

```
import emoji

with open("file.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        elements = []
        col = line.strip('\n')
        cols = col.split('\t')
        elements.append(cols)

        emoji_list = []
        data = re.findall(r'\X', elements)
        for word in data:
            if any(char in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI for char in word):
                emoji_list.append(word)
```

First try

```
import emoji

with open("file.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        elements = []
        col = line.strip('\n')
        cols = col.split('\t')
        elements.append(cols)

        emoji_list = []

        for c in elements:
            if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI:
                emojilist.append(c)
```

Second Try

I tried the examples which were given here [How to extract all the emojis from text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146528/how-to-extract-all-the-emojis-from-text) but they kinda didn't work for me and I'm not sure what I did wrong.

I'd really appreciate any help to extract the emoticons, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Your indentation is wrong; after the `for line in f:` you need to indent the rest.

Comment: Why there is no  emoticon in the expected output?

Comment: I want it to create a list with emoticons for every line especially, not for the whole dataset at once.
So I also need to consider the lines which contain no emoticons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emojis exist in several Unicode ranges, represented by this regex pattern:

```
>>> import re
>>> emoji = re.compile('[\\u203C-\\u3299\\U0001F000-\\U0001F644]')
```

You can use that to filter your lists:

```
>>> list(filter(emoji.match, ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test', 'tweet', 'with', 'two', 'emoticons', '', '⚓️']))
['', '⚓️']
```

*N.B.: The pattern is an approximation and may capture some additional characters.*

Comment: Thank you very, very much! :)