# Compare emoticons and put spaces around them in python

Tags: python-3.x, emoji, emoticons

I have a dataset and ,when I am encountering an emoticons without any space , I want to place space around them but I don't know few things

- I have this list

  ```
  sentences=["HiRob","swiggy",""].
  ```

  how to compare them as they are stored as strings.
- How to put spaces around them?

  Desired output

  ```
  sentences=["HiRob  ","swiggy","   "]
  ```

My basic problem is to put spaces around them.

Comment: Your output is inconsistent: Why is there no space _after_ the emoji in the first string, but both before and after (not just inbetween) the two emojis in the last string?

Comment: My primary purpose is just to put space between emoji and other characters, having space at the end is not a necessary condition ,Let me edit to make it consistent

Comment: [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404752/removing-emojis-from-a-string-in-python) seems to be related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [emoji package](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/) to simplify a bit your code.

```
from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI

# search your emoji
def is_emoji(s, language="en"):
    return s in UNICODE_EMOJI[language]

# add space near your emoji
def add_space(text):
    return ''.join(' ' + char if is_emoji(char) else char for char in text).strip()

sentences=["HiRob","swiggy",""]
results=[add_space(text) for text in sentences]

print(results)
```

output

```
['HiRob ', 'swiggy', ' ']
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/repls/EdibleUnluckyAlphatest)

related to: [How to extract all the emojis from text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146528/how-to-extract-all-the-emojis-from-text)

if `add_space` looks like black magic, here is a friendlier alternative:

```
def add_space(text):
  result = ''
  for char in text:
    if is_emoji(char):
      result += ' '
    result += char
  return result.strip()
```

Comment: There is an issue ,it works fine for the emoticons but now,it is removing the white spaces for the regular sentences.The output for `[Hi Rob]` is `[HiRob]`

Comment: Thanks, I am new to python so I have another doubt, could you elaborate this line more `return ''.join(' ' + char if is_emoji(char) else char for char in text).strip()` .I am getting ,you are adding a space using a join if it is emoji but I want to see your thought process

Comment: ok I will add a beginner alternative to add_space. Check the update.

Comment: There is a problem in is_emoji  function. you need to change it this way -> 

from emoji import unicode_codes
def is_emoji(s):
    return s in unicode_codes.UNICODE_EMOJI['en']

Comment: @A.Najafi could you post a link to showcase the error? I cant try this code right now.

Comment: @aloisdg Sure => https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CGmHBEYWLU3ayDeTmisOZkbF5WOn6Y5Z?usp=sharing