# Create an emoji column in python DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, emoji

I'm trying to extract emojis from customer reviews into a separate column in python DataFrame.
The code I'm using is:

def emojis(review):
    Content = review

```
for i in Content:
    if i in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI:
        return i
    else:
        return 'NaN'
```

The problem is that it doesn't pick up all emojis from Content. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146528/how-to-extract-all-the-emojis-from-text

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a list comprehension.

In this line:

```
for i in Content:
    if i in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI:
```

It will always return False since you are checking the entire content if it is in `emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI`.

So what you need is something like:

```
emoji_list = []
dummy_list = []
for i in Content:
    dummy_list.extend([c for c in Content if c in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI])
    if len(dummy_list) == 0:
        emoji_list.append(np.nan)
    else:
        emoji_list.append(dummy_list)
    dummy_list = []
```

You don't have a sample in your question so just take the answer above as how the logic goes.

We used `lists` because you want a column on a dataframe per entry/row of your content.

Simply use `df['Emoji entry on that content'] = emoji_list`