# Replace special characters with "N/A" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, special-characters

I would like to change all rows with only emojis such as `df['Comments'][2]` to N/A.

```
df['Comments'][:6]
0                                                          nice
1                                                       Insane3
2                                                          ❤️
3                                                @bertelsen1986
4                       20 or 30 mm rise on the Renthal Fatbar?
5                                     Luckily I have one to
```

The following code doesn't return the output I expect:

```
df['Comments'].replace(';', ':', '!', '*', np.NaN)
```

Expected Output:

```
df['Comments'][:6]
0                                                          nice
1                                                       Insane3
2                                                          nan
3                                                @bertelsen1986
4                       20 or 30 mm rise on the Renthal Fatbar?
5                                     Luckily I have one to
```

Comment: You don't want to replace `` in last line?

Comment: if it is possible to keep them, I would like to keep them. But if the code is too complex, then removing them are also okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function (remove_emoji) reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/61839832/6075699

Try
Install first `emoji` lib - `pip install emoji`

```
import re
import emoji

df.Comments.apply(lambda x: x if (re.sub(r'(:[!_\-\w]+:)', '', emoji.demojize(x)) != "") else np.nan)
0                         nice
1                      Insane3
2                          NaN
3               @bertelsen1986
4    Luckily I have one to 
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect lines containing *only* emojis by iterating over the unicode characters in each line (using the [emoji](https://pypi.org/project/emoji/) and [unicodedata](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) packages):

```
df = {}
df['Comments'] = ["Test", "Hello ", ""]

import unicodedata
import numpy as np
from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI
for i in range(len(df['Comments'])):
    pure_emoji = True
    for unicode_char in unicodedata.normalize('NFC', df['Comments'][i]):
        if unicode_char not in UNICODE_EMOJI:
            pure_emoji = False
            break
    if pure_emoji:
        df['Comments'][i] = np.NaN
print(df['Comments'])
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't have any effects on my code. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: You are right, it didn't write back the result correctly. I modified the example for correctly writing everything back into the ``df`` array and I verified that it works. Make sure to try it again now and consider marking my answer as solution as I posted it first.