# How to check if a message contains an emoji in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, emoji

I've created a bot that allows to create only-emojis text channels.
Now, I have the code, but how can I check if the message sent by the user contains any type of emoji (not customs)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146528/how-to-extract-all-the-emojis-from-text).

Comment: I don't have to extract emojis, but check if the message contains only emojis.

Comment: You could create a list containing all emojis. But this list would be really large. So it's better to create list with all letters (upper and lower case), numbers and additional characters. Then you just need to check, whether they are not contained.