# How to extract emojis from text and then add them to a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, emoji

I am wondering how to extract all the emojis from text, then add them to a new column while removing them from the original text - if that makes sense.

For example, consider this data:

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | This is good |
| 2 | Loving you so much ❤️ |
| 3 | You make me sad! |

This is my anticipated output:

| ID | Text | Emoji |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | This is good |  |
| 2 | Loving you so much | ❤️ |
| 3 | You make me sad! |  |

So far, I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146528/how-to-extract-all-the-emojis-from-text) solution, but it has not worked for me, as it does not remove the emoji from the original text.

Any help on how to do this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the following line should work for your purposes:

```
import pandas as pd
import emoji as emj

EMOJIS = emj.UNICODE_EMOJI["en"]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "text": [
            "This is good ",
            "Loving you so much  ❤️",
            "You make me sad! ",
        ]
    }
)

def extract_emoji(df):
    df["emoji"] = ""
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for emoji in EMOJIS:
            if emoji in row["text"]:
                row["text"] = row["text"].replace(emoji, "")
                row["emoji"] += emoji

extract_emoji(df)
print(df.to_string())
```

```
           text                  emoji
0      This is good               
1      Loving you so much  ️       ❤️
2      You make me sad!
```

Note that `extract_emoji` modifies the `DataFrame` in place.

Comment: Wow, thank you so, so much for that! It works! I really appreciate it!

Comment: ```EMOJIS = emj.UNICODE_EMOJI["en"]``` no longer works in [version 2.0.0](https://github.com/carpedm20/emoji/issues/221). Needs to be up-dated with ```EMOJIS = emj.EMOJI_DATA```. Function deletes text in original variable and does not extract emojis. Will post solution once found. [Possible solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146528/how-to-extract-all-the-emojis-from-text)